# Create UI using XAML similar to mac XAML wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to make an interface inside my window similar to what shown in the picture.

I have used mouseover triggers to achieve the certain functionality after making the images into controls. But it didn't work. I am developing a Desktop application. Tried couple of answers here but no luck for me.

Any theoretical guideline to achieve this UI? What if I just want to use mouseover triggers? Is it possible?[image]

Comment: I don't think it's possible just using mouseover triggers, because that wouldn't scale the adjacent icons.

Comment: What else should i use? behaviours along with triggers?

Comment: You can try FishEyePanel http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15705/FishEyePanel-FanPanel-Examples-of-custom-layout-pa

Comment: Try this even http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mgrayson/archive/2007/02/26/fish-eye-for-the-blend-guy.aspx

Comment: Try creating a custom panel - http://www.wpftutorial.net/CustomLayoutPanel.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be done with a mouseenter trigger if you do something like this

```
<Image Name="image1" Source="myimg.png" Height="100"/>
<Image Name="image2" Source="myim2.png" Height="100"/>
<Image Name="image3" Source="myimg3.png" Height="100" MouseOver="do_This"/>
<Image Name="image4" Source="myimg4.png" Height="100"/>
<Image Name="image5" Source="myimg.png" Height="100"/>
```

Then in your code behind

```
void do_This()
{
    this.image3.Height = 150;
    this.image1.Height = 110;
    this.image2.Height = 120;
    this.image4.Height = 120;
    this.image5.Height = 110;
}
```

That's the basic idea you would just have to adjust for each image you mouse over, however keep in mind that you also have a mouseleave event that resets the images back to the original size.

You don't need to use vector images for this solution but make sure your image is larger than what you need since images will look better scaled down than scaled up.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using images for the controls, use vector graphics. That gives one more flexibility to change size, color and other attributes of what is being seen as needed for the process needed.

See [How do I Include Vector-Based Image Resources in my WPF Application?](http://learnwpf.com/post/2006/06/04/How-do-I-Include-Vector-Based-Image-Resources-in-my-WPF-Application.aspx) to get you started.